# Input string to binary tree inorder traversal

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am creating a program that accepts the bracket notation of a binary tree, and then provides various functions such as inorder traversal.

For the sake of this example: Input is G(Y(u)(5))(2(t)).

When traversing through the tree, my code only returns Y G u , but it should return u Y 5 G 2 t.

My main method provides a GUI for the user to enter the binary tree string. I have a separate class that constructs the binary tree and contains a private class that constructs each node.

I have reviewed my code, but can't quite figure out what the issue is.
I have checked out Geeks for Geeks as well as YouTube videos, but I am having issues grasping the concept.

```
public class BinaryTree {
    Node root;
    Node parent;
    Character c;
    String r;
    String tree;

    public BinaryTree(String tree) { // constructor
        this.tree = tree;
    }

    public Node strToTree(String tree) {
        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>(); 
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>(); 
        String[] a = tree.split(""); 
        int i = 0;

        while (i < tree.length()) { // holds string's chars
            queue.add(a[i]);
            i = i + 1;
        }

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) { 
                String b = queue.remove();
            if (!b.equals("(")) {
                stack.push(b); // stores closed brackets, number, & letters
                if (b.equals(")") & !stack.isEmpty()) {
                    stack.pop(); // parenthesis
                    String e = stack.pop(); // character
                    String f = stack.lastElement();
                    c = e.charAt(0);
                    char g = f.charAt(0);
                    root = new Node(c);
                    parent = new Node(g);
                    if (parent.left == null) {
                        parent.left = root;
                        parent = parent.left;
                    } else
                        parent.right = root;
                }
            }
        }

        return root;
    }

    public void inOrderTraverse(String tree) {
        Node root = new Node(tree.charAt(0));
        Node left = new Node(tree.charAt(2));
        Node right = new Node(tree.charAt(4));
        getString(tree);
        root.inOrderTraverse(left);
        root.inOrderTraverse(root);
        root.inOrderTraverse(right);
        root.inOrderTraverse(left.left); // testing case
    }

    static class Node {
        char data;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        Node root;

        private Node(char data) { // constructor
            this.data = data;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }

        public void inOrderTraverse(Node root) {
            if (root == null)
                return;

            /* first recur on left child */
            inOrderTraverse(root.left);
            // (root.left);

            /* then print the data of node */
            System.out.print(root.data + " ");

            /* now recur on right child */
            inOrderTraverse(root.right);// root.right);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in `strToTree` is not correct. Some of the issues:

- Every time a ")" is processed the `root` variable is overwritten with a new node -- so losing whatever was there before.
- It cannot be right that you would have to create *two* nodes whenever a ")" is encountered.
- `stack.lastElement()` may be executed on an empty stack...
- By setting `parent.right = root;` you admit that `root` has a parent, so then `return root` is not returning the root.
- `if (parent.left == null) {` might not be the right way to detect that the left child has to receive the new child. Consider that an input might have `A()(C)` to indicate that "A" has no left child, but does have a right child (C). You would need to somehow register that `()` was the input for the *left* child, keeping it `null`, while the next information would serve for a right child.
- ...

Some other remarks:

- The `Node` class should not have a `root` member. Only the `BinaryTree` class should have that.
- The `BinaryTree` class should not need `parent` (a tree has no parent), `c` (that should just be a local variable), `r` (?), nor even `tree` (as that is string input that should immediately be converted to the tree itself -- there is no need to persist that). So the only property a tree needs is its `root`.
- `strToTree` should better return a new `BinaryTree` instance instead of a `Node`. So it should be a static method, or even better, a constructor for the class.
- I don't see what you intended to do with the `inOrderTraverse` method you have on the `BinaryTree` class. It should just call the method with the same name on the `Node` class.
- The `inOrderTraverse` method on the `Node` class should be static (it doesn't use the *current* node `this`).
- Using a `Queue` is overkill. You can just iterate the characters of the input string.
- To keep track of whether the next token in the input string is about a left or a right child, you could also stack a boolean for each node that is on the stack. You could for instance have a stack of pairs <Node, Boolean>, or just two stacks that operate in tandem.

Here is an overhaul of your code:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    Node root;

    public BinaryTree(String input) {
        root = null;
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Boolean> sidestack = new Stack<>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char ch = input.charAt(i);
            if (ch == ')') {
                if (input.charAt(i-1) != '(') { // Exclude empty node 
                    stack.pop(); // This node has no more children to add
                    sidestack.pop();
                }
            } else if (ch != '(') {
                Node node = new Node(ch);
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    root = node; 
                } else {
                    boolean side = sidestack.peek();
                    if (side) {
                        stack.peek().right = node;
                    } else {
                        stack.peek().left = node;
                    }
                    sidestack.pop();
                    sidestack.push(!side); // Toggle child
                }
                stack.push(node);
                sidestack.push(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void inOrderTraverse() {
        Node.inOrderTraverse(root);
    }
    
    static class Node {
        char data;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        private Node(char data) { // constructor
            this.data = data;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }

        static public void inOrderTraverse(Node root) {
            if (root == null)
                return;
            inOrderTraverse(root.left);
            System.out.print(root.data + " ");
            inOrderTraverse(root.right);
        }
    }

    // Demo
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "G(Y(u)(5))(2()(t))";
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(input);
        tree.inOrderTraverse();
    }
    
}
```